# Allocating array of abstract type in Fortran

Tags: oop, types, fortran, subroutine

Basically, I have an **abstract class** a **wrapper class** and a **base class** which are defined in the **Base Module**. The abbstract class holds an allocatable array and a subroutine. In the constructor I want to allocate this array but that does not work.

The allocation does work for `Base` but I guess that is not what I want as the Child Class does not know anything from `Base`. How would I do this allocation?

Here's what I have:

**Base Module**

```c
module BaseClass

    implicit none

    ! ------------------------
    ! ABSTRACT CLASS
    ! ------------------------
    type, abstract :: AbsBaseHelper
        real, allocatable :: A(:)  !! <-- this makes problems
    contains
        procedure :: construct
        procedure(help_int), deferred :: help
    end type

    ! ------------------------
    ! WRAPPER CLASS
    ! ------------------------
    type :: BaseWrap
        integer :: cI
        class(AbsBaseHelper), pointer :: p
    contains
        procedure :: do_something
    end type

    ! ------------------------
    ! INTERFACE
    ! ------------------------
    interface
        subroutine help_int(this)
            import AbsBaseHelper
            implicit none
            class(AbsBaseHelper), intent(inout) :: this
        end subroutine help_int
    end interface

    ! ------------------------
    ! BASE CLASS
    ! ------------------------
    type(BaseWrap) :: Base(2)

contains

    ! ------------------------
    ! CONSTRUCTOR
    ! ------------------------
    subroutine construct(this, id)

        implicit none
        class(AbsBaseHelper), intent(in), target :: this
        integer, intent(in) :: id

        Base(id)%cI =  id
        ! allocate( this%A(2) )         !! <-- does not work because this is only intent(in)
        Base(id)%p  => this
        allocate( Base(id)%p%A(2) )     !! <-- does not work because it gives segmentation fault in 'help'

    end subroutine construct

    ! ------------------------
    ! THE MAIN SUBROUTINE
    ! ------------------------
    subroutine do_something(this)

        implicit none

        class(BaseWrap), intent(inout) :: this

        print*, "Base Index : ", this%cI
        call this%p%help()
        print*, "Result 1 : ", this%p%A(1)
        print*, "Result 2 : ", this%p%A(2)

    end subroutine do_something

end module BaseClass
```

**Child Module**

```c
module ChildClass1

    use BaseClass

    implicit none

    type, extends(AbsBaseHelper) :: Child1
    contains
        procedure :: help
    end type

contains

    subroutine help(this)
        implicit none
        class(Child1), intent(inout) :: this

        this%A(1) = 1   !! <-- produces segmentation fault
        this%A(2) = 2
    end subroutine

end module ChildClass1
```

**The Program**

```c
program test

    use BaseClass

    implicit none

    call init
    call Base(1)%do_something()

contains

    ! ------------------------
    ! INITIALIZE
    ! ------------------------
    subroutine init

        use ChildClass1

        implicit none

        type(Child1), target :: c1

        call c1%construct(1)

    end subroutine init

end program test
```

Comment: Could you please try to reduce your problem to a [mcve] (shorter)? There is a lot going on there, this may be uninvitative for users to put attention in your question.

Comment: Hi @RodrigoRodrigues! I now completely reformulated the question and trid to minify it to the maximum possible. I hope this still makes sense.

Comment: The errors in the code seem to have little to do with the question title.  Consider the lifetime of the local variable `c1` in the internal procedure `init` of the main program, and what happens to pointers that are associated with that local variable.  Consider also the `intent(in)` attribute being applied to a dummy argument that apparently needs to be defined by the relevant procedure.  In terms of the code in the question, consider describing what you are trying to do, as well as how you are trying to do it.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @IanH. Unfortunately this is the point; I don't know how to solve this. Any suggestions what I could try?

Comment: Dummy arguments of type `class` should be `intent(inout)`.